# Equivalent function of pytesseract.image_to_data in tesserocr

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I am currently using `pytesseract.image_to_data` on several images but this is incredibly slow so I was thinking of moving over to `tesserocr`.

I can't seem to find an equivalent function though that gives me the positions of all the pieces of text on the page as well as breaking them into levels, paragraphs, line numbers and word numbers.